# ObjectiveC target can't find module, Swift working fine

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks

I'm building a framework that needs to work with Swift **and** Objective-C. It is built with Swift.

It works fine in a Swift app. `@import MyFrameworkName` works just as expected. But I can't seem to make it work in an Objective-C app.

```
#import <MyFrameworkName/MyFrameworkName-Swift.h>
```

This is the build log:

```
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "Headers/MyFrameworkName.h"
        ^
/Users/user/Projects/MyFrameworkName/Sources/MyFrameworkName.h:20:9: error: module 'CommonCryptoBridge' not found
@import CommonCryptoBridge;
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'MyFrameworkName'
```

This is my framework header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

FOUNDATION_EXPORT double MyFrameworkNameVersionNumber;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char MyFrameworkNameVersionString[];    
@import CommonCryptoBridge;
```

The `CommonCryptoBridge` is a module to enable `CommonCrypto` in Swift, defined by `CommonCryptoBridge.h` and `CommonCryptoBridge.modulemap`:

CommonCryptoBridge.h

```
#ifndef __COMMONCRYPTO_BRIDGE__
#include <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>
#define __COMMONCRYPTO_BRIDGE__
#endif /* __COMMONCRYPTO_BRIDGE__ */
```

CommonCryptoBridge.modulemap

```
module CommonCryptoBridge [system] {
    header "CommonCryptoBridge.h"
    export *
}
```

Comment: solve this problem?

Comment: @Jack I'm sorry, we ended up leaving the project on hold. We still have this issue (presumably, unless a swift update fixed this)